# The server returned a malformed response when using echo in PHP to output large binary string to HTTP response

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to output some large binary array to HTTP response with the following code:

```
$bin = NULL;

$strLenToOutput = 8000;

for ($i=0; $i < $strLenToOutput; $i++) {
    $bin .= pack("C", 1);
}

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.bin");
header("Content-Length: filesize=" . strlen($bin));
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");

echo $bin;
```

when the string to output is relatively short, <= 8000, the code above works fine. But if string length increases to 8001, I will get the following error in Postman:

```
Parse Error: The server returned a malformed response
```

I am running PHP7.4 on Apache V2.4.46, all default settings.

What did I do wrong here? Code in PHP or some settings on Apache2 that I need to change?

Please advise and thanks in advance.

Update: it seems if I remove the following line that sets file length, the PHP code will work. I guess the problem is I should let PHP itself take care of that part.

```
//header("Content-Length: filesize=" . strlen($bin));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how Content-Length header is set. The original code sets a header

```
header("Content-Length: filesize=" . strlen($bin));
```

It should be set like the following:

```
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($bin));
```

The additional text "filesize=" in header just messes up parsing of response on client side. When Content-Length is <= 8000, clients may have someway to recover, but unable to cope if Content-Length >= 8001